# How to execute Azure DevOps Task extension with powershell 7?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-extensions, tfs-2018

I have a custom task which basically executes a powershell script. I have been running this with Powershell 5.1 on the build machine, how do I force execute this into Powershell 7?

This calls Powershell 5.1
`"execution": { "Powershell": { "target": "widgetUpload.ps1", "argumentFormat": "", "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)" }`

Trying to call Powershell 7 with below, but doesn't work.

`"execution": { "pwsh": { "target": "widgetUpload.ps1", "argumentFormat": "", "workingDirectory": "$(currentDirectory)" }`

We are on TFS 2018.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option. There is no PowerShell Core execution handler.

The only thing you can do is add a wrapper script that calls `pwsh` from the Windows PowerShell. That's also how the `PowerShell@2` tasks does it:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/a1fb3829bbfe59c6fa0ace05e0f81a52da8fc8db/Tasks/PowerShellV2/powershell.ps1#L149-L180

You should upgrade to the `PowerShell3` handler though, but that will still rely on PowerShell 5.1.